# Maven web project, Class not found Exception in war for external jars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven web project for which i was required to include some third party jars (not present online) so i installed them using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smas.cluster</groupId>
    <artifactId>cluster-smas</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/cluster-smas-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The Problem which i am facing is when i run maven clean install the war file generated didnot included the 3rd party jar. 
After searching i found a solution i copied jar in lib folder (created at root directory of project) and Then i used following snippet in Pom file

```
<plugin> 
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>2.0.2</version> 
        <configuration> 
          <webResources> 
            <resource> 
              <directory>${project.basedir}/libs/</directory> 
              <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath> 
            </resource> 
          </webResources> 
        </configuration> 
  </plugin> 
</plugins>
```

The jar are now copied from my lib folder to WEB-INF/lib/ in generated war file. But when i run the service i get error of Class not found exception.

Comment: Can you show the error? If the lib is in the lib folder and you still are receiving that error it means that the missing class is not present in that jar. Maybe it is from a dependency of it.

Comment: I have checked the jar the class is there. May be the reason is i am adding jars not in proper way as it should be done in maven ?

Comment: have you checked if the running container (e.g tomcat)  where your war file should be actually have that jar on it?

Comment: post the full error trace also.

Comment: Put jar file into tomcat /lib directory and restart tomcat.

Comment: Yes i have checked 
the war file contains the lib (since i used maven plugin to copy jar to WEB-INT\lib)

Comment: If i add libs to tomcat explicitly 
whats the benefit of maven project then if i have to copy and paste jar here and there

Comment: Why are you using the `system` scope for your 3rd party dependencies? I think you should be using the `compile` scope (which is the default). See [Maven Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Comment: It worked when i added jars manually in deployment assembly (i am using Eclipse IDE)

Comment: `system` scope is similar to `provided` scope and indicates that you expect the system to provide the dependency, so maven will not include it in your artifact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, remove `system` scope and `systemPath`, and remove the war plugin, leaving just the dependency declaration.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smas.cluster</groupId>
    <artifactId>cluster-smas</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Build your project. Your dependency JAR should appear in WEB-INF/lib and the classes will be available at runtime.